# Vi changes in Debian 8 -> Debian 9

Tags: linux, debian, vi

I updated a Debian server from Debian 8 to Debian 9 and now I've noticed `vi` behaves quite differently. Is it because of the update in Debian or something else? For example before I could write `/term` to search for a term and then just `/` to go to the next find etc. but now it starts highlighting words and jumping around and all sorts of weird things!

Also when I paste a block of code in to a file it does something weird with the indentation so the bottom of the block is way over on to the right, huge indentation.

And also all sorts of auto indentation etc. which I use to do manually.

I guess this is because `vi` is a newer version in `Debian 9` maybe? Can I make it all behave the same as the previous version or downgrade somehow ?

Comment: `n` was always the vim command for the next search result. If it's highlighting and it didn't used to it's because of a change in the default `hlsearch`. We're talking about vim, not vi, right?

Comment: i use `vi` , not `vim ` ? i just use to press `/` for next result, it never used to start highlighting then

Comment: you could use `/<RETURN>` to get to the next result, idk how just `/` could've worked. If you don't want highlighting you should do :set nohlsearch
if that works add `set nohlsearch` to your `~/.vimrc`, I'd be pretty surprised if you were actually using vi

Answer (score 3):

Yes this version of vim editor is a little different than the previous version
`type /term` (desire search word)
Take the cursor on a word and hit the * key to the next instance of that word.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you uninstall the present version of vi you have installed and install a version of vi you are familiar with, it means you have to specify the version of vi editor during installation.

Hope this helps...
Cheers,